# Using NSCache: Not clearing or removing memory how I expect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am using NSCache for my iOS app.  I know that it will handle its own memory, but I want to purge it manually.  When I tell it to removeAllObjects I don't see my memory usage go down in Instruments Allocations.

Is there another way that this would happen or does it not empty its memory how I am thinking?

Answer (score 0):

NSCache will retain objects you add to it.

*Is it possible your alloc'ing objects, adding to the cache and not releasing leading to a retain count of 2?*  Narrowing it down to a small snippet that reproes the behavior with posted code may help narrow it.

Per docs:

> While a key-value pair is in the cache, the cache maintains a strong
>   reference to it if garbage collection is in effect; in memory-managed
>   code, **the cache retains the item**.

Also, here's a video showing working with NSCache and allocations - in that example, they can removeAllObjects under a memory warning.  they simulate a memory warning and it does reduce the memory footprint so it should work ...

http://speirs.org/blog/2010/6/30/using-instruments-to-learn-about-nscache.html

Comment: Thanks. I am not seeing that there are any memory leaks, so I don't think that has a retain count of 2. I will try out a smaller example and look at the video.